# Entity Framework Navigation Property on many-to-one relationship

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

**Edited**

I am trying to set up a many-to-one relationship on two tables I have got but I am unable to manage to make it work. I tried different options but I end up retrieving records of only one table.

Below is my table structure:

**Customer**

```
[Table("Customer")]
public class CustomerList
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public int? MembershipTypeID { get; set; }
    public MembershipTypeList MembershipType { get; set; }
    public string Name;

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

**MembershipType**

```
[Table("MembershipType")]
public class MembershipTypeList
{
    [Key]
    public int? MembershipTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //public virtual CustomerList Customer { get; set; }
}
```

**Result**

```
CustomerID 56
Number 52
Surname Antonelli
Forename Renny
DateOfBirth 1945-02-19
MembershipTypeID 1
EmailAddress Mr@test.com
Name NULL
```

**Expected**

```
CustomerID 56 
Number 52 
Surname Antonelli 
Forename Renny 
DateOfBirth 1945-02-19 
MembershipTypeID 1 
EmailAddress Mr@test.com 
Name Blue ---> from membershiptype table
```

Comment: Firstly. Why does each class name end in List? They obviously aren't lists. Secondly, this isn't a One-One mapping. Unless every `Customer` has a different type. In which case that is a pretty useless way to categorize your customers. Finally, you want to put virtual on your `MembershipType` property, OR you can use `.Include(x => x.MembershipType)` on your query.

Comment: Aron, what I need to have is to, include the Name column from MembershipType table in my resultset. I think. with the Include statement that would be possible but I am unable to understand, why it doesn't displays in the resultset along with records from Customer or is it not possible.

Comment: I do not understand. Are you using EF? What do you mean ResultSet and Column?

Comment: I am using Resultset word just to refer the records I see in intellisense. I am using this statement `var customerList = from tsk in db.DbCustomerList.Include("MembershipType") select tsk;`

Comment: And column? What do you mean by column?

Comment: Column means Table field (Name from MembershipType table). I think I am close with this statement `var customerList = from tsk in db.DbCustomerList.Include("MembershipType").ToList() select tsk;` It shows now the MembershipType Table record in the list, but when I hover over customerList (var), it doesn't returns any records. Any idea

Comment: Because it's not one to one...plus you commented it out. This is many to one mapping.